# Wordpress meta query

Tags: wordpress, meta-query

I have created a theme with a custom post type of `reports`. I installed a rating plugin that interacts with this post type, allowing users to rate the reports. It stores the post rating in two fields, `sum` and `count` where sum is the total for all ratings, and count is the number of individual ratings.

Example: If a 5 people rated a post as 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, the `sum` would be `15` and the `count` would be `5`.

When a user visits the `reports` archive page, they see a list of all posts of the `report` post type. However, I want to add a query parameter to filter down to posts with an average rating of 4 or higher. I'm currently trying to use the `pre_get_posts` hook as follows:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'filterReports' );

function filterReports( $query ) {
  if( is_post_type_archive( 'reports' ) && $_GET['top'] ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = $wpdb->prepare(
      "SELECT * 
      FROM 
        wp_postmeta AS sum
        wp_postmeta AS count
      WHERE
        sum.meta_key = 'sum' AND
        count.meta_key = 'count' AND
        sum.meta_value / count.meta_value >= 4"
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to construct my custom query in the above. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code will work as per your scenario.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'filterReports' );

function filterReports( $query ) {
  if( is_post_type_archive( 'reports' ) && $_GET['top'] ) {
     $reports_meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

     //Add our meta query to the original meta queries
     $reports_meta_query[] = array(
                    'key'=>'count',
                    'value'=> 4,
                    'compare'=>'>=',
                );
     $query->set('meta_query',$reports_meta_query);
     // somehow construct a query that checks if sum / count >= 4
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like this will get all reports that have been rated more than four times. I need to filter on all reports where dividing the `sum` by the `count` results in a number that is `>= 4`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the query you are looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT 
 sum.post_id,
 sum.meta_value,
 count.meta_value,
 (sum.meta_value / count.meta_value) as result
  FROM 
    wp_postmeta sum
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta count USING(post_id)
  WHERE
    sum.meta_key = 'sum' AND
    count.meta_key = 'count'
  HAVING 
    result >= 4
```

You are basically joining twice the same table based on the post_id, so you can then query by the meta_key of both sum and count, then you look for the result of your math in a `Having` clause to check if the result would be bigger than 4 as requested.

Hope with this you can get what you were looking for.

Cheers